# How do I create a button that clears off all labels in tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, widget

What my code does currently is create a label with the text "Hello" every time I press the button that says "Say hello"

What I'm trying to figure out is how to create a button that clears off all of the labels off the screen, however I'm completely clueless.

How do I create a button that clears all of the labels off of the screen?

My code is down below.

```
import tkinter as tk
import time

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("700x500")

h = "Hello"

def CreateLabel():
    helloLabel = tk.Label(root, text=h)
    helloLabel.pack()

labelButton = tk.Button(root, text="Say hello", command=CreateLabel)
labelButton.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Are you aware that you don't have to delete and recreate widgets? You can change the text on an existing widget, which will be slightly more efficient than deleting and recreating.

Answer (score 2):

I'm beginner but try this:

```
import tkinter as tk
import time

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("700x500")

h = "Hello"
liste = []

def CreateLabel():
    helloLabel = tk.Label(root, text=h)
    helloLabel.pack()
    liste.append(helloLabel)

def DelLabel():
     for i in range(len(liste)):
        liste[i].destroy()
     liste.clear()


labelButton = tk.Button(root, text="Say hello", command=CreateLabel)
labelButton.pack()
labelButton = tk.Button(root, text="del hello", command=DelLabel)
labelButton.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Better call `liste.clear()` after the for loop inside `DelLabel()` so that next time `DelLabel()` is called, already destroyed labels will not be destroyed again.

Comment: @farlescharris can you accept this answer ?